# Encrypt files without leaving a hint of the encryption algorithm used

Tags: encryption, aes, software

I noticed after encrypting some files with **7zip** that they contained the information about the encryption algorithm used AES 256, i want to know if there is a better software that doesn't leave traces about the nature of encryption because with such information this will simplify the task of deciphering by the attacker.

I think that the security wouldn't be good if the encryption software is adding metadata or inserting an ID somewhere in header leaving hints about the nature of file (7zip compressed), the version used and the encryption algorithm name.

What can you suggest ? thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type "what product/service does X?" are off-topic. If you want to rephrase your question about whether this metadata is a problem, we can re-open.

Answer (score 3):

Any given encryption system should be secure even if everything except the key is public. This is a basic principle of encryption as stated by [Kerckhoffs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle).

VeraCrypt for example offers the creation of "hidden volumes" which not only make it not obvious which encryption algorithm is used, but also hide that there actually is anything encrypted.

Although according to [VeraCrypt's documentation](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Hidden%20Volume.html), this is more of an approach to prevent extortion when attackers know that there might be some sensitive information around.
Normally, the humans knowing the access procedure are much weaker than the encryption algorithms used.

Notice: This can also be the other way around.
Attackers sometimes back off when seeing that a very secure and slow algorithm is used for encryption as very secure algorithm often come along with secure keys. This does NOT mean, that you should use insecure algorithms!

Comment: Yeah but the concept of hidding volumes in Veracrypt supports my point of view, there is a need to conceal that a file is encrypted, if an attacker couldn't say if an encrypted volume exist would increase the security of data the same applies to individual files, if no hints are there the attacker couldn't tell if the file is encrypted or a corrupted video file for example.

Comment: *Attackers sometimes back off when ...* - why do you mention this at all? It sounds like you believe that the encryption you use is actually *weak* and you fear that attackers will break it, and you will be happy if they don't continue. Such view might implicitly promote usage of insecure methods based just on the hope that serious attackers will not spend time analyzing and brute-forcing them.

Comment: @mentallurg What about hidden volumes then ? It's not about not trusting the encryption algorithm, it's about not giving hints that a given file is encrypted or encrypted using a particular method, i search something that will output a raw file that couldn't be identified that it's encrypted without doing extra analysis work.

Comment: @dmuensterer: Assumptions? :) I am just wondering what can be the reason. Many users that will read this statement *may* believe that one of methods to get security is to keep attackers off. Thus based on your answer they can implement insecure methods hoping that some trick they implemented will keep attacker off and will give them security. Where as this will of course give no security.

Comment: @P.Kod: Hidden volumes can help only against beginners who don't really understand cryptography.

Answer (score 3):

I don't agree that such information should be secret. Think of [Kerckhoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle). Security should be based not on the secrecy of *method*, but on the secrecy of the *key*.

Comment: Don't you think that hiding the fact that a file is encrypted would keep the file safe from being an object of attack, this is my point.

Comment: When you are encrypting anything, you should *expect* that it *will be* an object of analysis and brute-forcing.

Comment: Yes but in other words i said that hiding an encrypted file could make it appear like if it's not encrypted at all, why would you try to brute-force a file you don't know if it's encrypted or just filled with random data ?

Comment: @P.Kod: When you are encrypting anything, you should *expect* that it *will be* an object of analysis and brute-forcing. Computer programs produce the same output for the same input and are relatively easily analyzable. Making encryption method obscure gives only *impression* to humans that this gives more security, where as actually it doesn't.

Comment: @P.Kod: ... Because if somebody wants to find out any information you want to keep secret, he/she will analyze any data they obtain. They will not analyze if a particular file contains a hint *encrypted by method ABC*. For instance, if particular file is not distinguishable from a random byte stream, it can be really garbage, but it can also be an encrypted data. If s file has some structure (like image), it would be checked against possible steganography.

Comment: I agree with you but imagine the attacker couldn't gain access to all your data but that file, it's all he have because he intercepted it in some manner, this is why i'm talking about hiding the encryption from an individual file.

Comment: @P.Kod: OK, in other words: If somebody is not much interested in your secrets, then he/she will not invest much time in brute-forcing your encrypted data. Thus, it makes no sense to hide any hints to encryption method. But if there is somebody who *really wants* to get your secrets, he/she will relatively easily get knowledge about methods used. Again, it makes no sense to invest efforts into hiding encryption method. Sure, you can do what ever you want. But you should know that this will not give you more security.

Comment: No it's not easy to know what method is used depending on the encryption algorithm, and this has nothing to do with attacker interested in my files or not, i'm talking about a given file (or a private photo of me) that could have been created a 10 years ago and it is present online with a wrong extension for example.

Comment: @P.Kod: It **is** easy. Please read what I wrote: *Computer programs produce the same output for the same input*. Suppose you implemented ZIP program that doesn't write info about encryption method use. An attacker will just debug it and will see what algorithms is used. If some company is using some special software for encryption, soon or later it *will* be known to attackers.

Comment: @P.Kod: Why it will be known? For instance, because this company has to order development of such software -> many people will know it, then they need to train users to use it, then they need to distribute this software to users, then periodically update, periodically create back up, some drive will be stolen or lost. It is almost inevitable to keep *method* secret. The price can be huge, but there still will be no guarantee. That's why serious companies understand that and don't spend efforts on hiding the *methods*. Instead, they keep *keys* secret.

Comment: @P.Kod: I cannot discuss it further.

Comment: @mentallurg "Computer programs produce the same output for the same input" -  what a bogus assumption!
Can you provide a proof for it?
I could name five algorithms off the top of my head that prove this statement to be wrong because they produce a different output without a traceable pattern.
A true random number generator would be an easy example.

Comment: @mentallurg The implicit question of the OP can be answered very easily by deriving a much simpler question:
Is it more effort for an attacker to decrypt data if he needs to do a comprehensive analysis of which algorithm is used before?
I assume you do know the answer.
That said, security through obscurity is not secure.

Comment: @dmuensterer: As I said, if the attacker has no strong interest or skill, then the info about methods gives him no advantage. If another attacker has strong desire to decrypt it and much resources, then getting info about the algorithms is the easiest part. And of course, professional attackers don't guess what method could it be (besides trivial cases like simple substitutions), instead the information is obtained from reliable source: from analysis of software use, from getting access to design documents, to user manuals etc. Hiding method is then very naive.